# Accessing sub-namespaces of a XAML namespace without defining a new xmlns

Tags: c#, wpf

This might just be impossible by the nature of XAML but this is my situation:

I am trying to access the namespace `NineGridViewer.ValidationRules` within my XAML. I currently have the namespace definition `xmlns:nineGridViewer="clr-namespace:NineGridViewer"`. Is it necessary to define a completely new namespace to access the ValidationRules namespace or is it possible to use my nineGridViewer xmlns to access subnamespaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access nested namespace from inside XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857034/how-to-access-nested-namespace-from-inside-xaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the assembly defining those classes, you can [create custom XML namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Mapping_CLR_Namespaces_to_XML_Namespaces_in_an) using an attribute:

> WPF defines a CLR attribute that is consumed by XAML processors in order to map multiple CLR namespaces to a single XAML namespace. This attribute, [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx), is placed at the assembly level in the source code that produces the assembly. The WPF assembly source code uses this attribute to map the various common namespaces, such as `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Controls`, to the http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation namespace.
>
> The [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) takes two parameters: the XML/XAML namespace name, and the CLR namespace name. More than one XmlnsDefinitionAttribute can exist to map multiple CLR namespaces to the same XML namespace.

Comment: This does not answer the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58857619/478765

Comment: @ed22: Yes it does, otherwise it would not have been accepted. Using nested namespaces directly only works in limited cases like the `x:Type` extension. Using `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` makes the types available everywhere, including element tags.